# SQL Files Syntax error check with liquibase

Tags: sql, shell, liquibase

We are deploying sql query's using liquibase automation tool.

liquibase version: 4.3.0

We have created DB files in SQL format and used the "liquibase validate" command to validate the syntax error. But I didn't get expected result.

Ex: dem1.sql, demo2.sql

I have found the below doc's for validation,

https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/validate.html?msclkid=72d2d27da9cf11ecae4cc3525df5294e

As per the above document, "liqubase validate" command won't support for SQL format files.

Can any one help me to validate the SQL format file with liquibase or any other ways (like shell script or jenkins pipeline stage) before deploy the sql query's to my DB.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach for syntax validation could be to utilise a Database [test-container](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/) matching your runtime environment during integration coverage.

That way your LiquiBase changelogs can be executed during test-setup and syntax is implicitly validated.

See example here (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testcontainers-integration-test)